# Saving a cropped image using php

Tags: php, gd, jcrop

I used JCrop to crop an image using the code I got from this website :
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html

php code:

```
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['afile']['tmp_name']);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);
```

Essentially what the php does is print the cropped image onto the screen.

However I would like to store this image in my `uploads` file on my server. Normally I would use `move_uploaded_file()`, but in this particular instance, I'm not sure what parameter value to give to `move_uploaded_file()`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can then change:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);
```

into:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/sample-file.jpg', $jpeg_quality);
```

The second parameter of [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) is location where you want to save the file. Of course `'uploads/sample-file.jpg'` is only sample, you need to change it to make it unique to not override other files

Comment: this should work, which is why I picked it as best answer, but for some reason it won't write to my folder. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the path I'm using, any suggestions?

Comment: It might have. Make sure directory exists and you have valid permissions set. Turn also error reporting and check if there are any errors or warnings